# Change field in model metadata to read only in runtime based on criteria

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, modelmetadata

I'm creating a generic interface for editing pages and on some pages eg the start page I need to disable or remove some fields. The form is rendered with Html.EditorFor. What is the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a [custom editor template](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-3-default-templates.html) for the given type (string, decimal, object, ...):

```
@model string
@Html.TextBox(
    "", 
    ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue,
    ViewData
)
```

and then:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Foo)
```

or in views where you want it to be disabled:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Foo, new { disabled = "disabled" })
```

Comment: Pretty easy solution but didn't think about it my self. Thanks!